# ¿Cómo llamar un método de un controller que tiene constructor?

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio, mvc, .net-5

Buen día a todos!
Tengo un error (que siento que es algo sencillo pero no se que es XD) al llamar un método de mi controller por medio de AJAX. Si en la clase de mi controller no existe un constructor, si me reconoce la ruta y funciona de maravilla, pero si agrego un constructor al controller ya no me reconoce la ruta del controller, ¿Esto a que se debe?

Este es el código de mi controller:

```
public class ValidadorController : Controller
{
    private readonly ValidadorServices _srvValidador;

    public ValidadorController(ValidadorServices srvValidador)
    {
        _srvValidador = srvValidador;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ValidarCredenciales()
    {
        var response = await _srvValidador.ValidarCredenciales();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Este es el código de mi JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Validador/ValidarCredenciales',
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        data === true ? modalValidacionCorrecta.show() : modalValidacionIncorrecta.show();
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Este es el error que me arroja en la consola: GET  https://localhost:44307/Validador/ValidarCredenciales 500

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto .NET 5 MVC

Comment: Normalmente el error 500 viene acompañado de cual es el error... que dice?

Comment: Estuve buscando y solo me arroja lo mencionado @Pipe

Comment: y que error te arroja en los logs del servidor?

Comment: He vuelto a checar el error y veo que esta llamando directamente al constructor, cuando NO deberia @Pipe

Comment: Yo no se mucho de .NET pero deberías tener algún sistema que te sirva para inyectar las dependencias del constructor, pero como no sé, no te puedo ayudar mas de ahí.